# Can the subject of a while clause be omitted?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

For example, instead of saying "consumers no longer take the horsepower of cars as the only criterion, while they also care about the fuel-consumption", can I say: "consumers no longer take the horsepower of cars as the only criterion, while also care about the fuel-consumption"?

In a word, I wonder whether the subject in the while clause can be omitted as long as it's identical to that of the main sentence? After all, the sentence reads fine after omitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your original sentence is faulty. To discuss the repetition of the subject in a malformed sentence would not be helpful!

The main culprit is *'while'*.

If we remove it we can make:

> Consumers no longer take the horsepower of cars as the/their only
> criterion: they also care about the/their oil-consumption.

Or we might use *although* instead:

> Although a car's horsepower remains a criterion, its
> oil-consumption has become equally important.

Or we can keep "while" and make:

> While consumers still see the horsepower of cars as one (important)
> criterion, they now also care about oil-consumption.

I think we tend to use 'while' for the old: not the new.

> While I still enjoy quinoa and goji berries, I've started eating more
> pork belly.

You say, "After all, the sentence reads fine".
Optimism is always welcome here at ELL! :-)

Comment: I think I'm going to agree with you that 'while' is often used for the old. In this way, there seems to be no more question about omitting the subject of a 'while' clause, because we just cannot. Pardon me for my English, I'm not a native speaker. And really thank you for you answer! I voted for it, but I don't have enough reputation to make it present right away.